# Upgrading project from Django 1.7 to 1.9- tests are not running

Tags: python, django, authentication, tastypie

After migrating the project and fixing migrations, unit tests cannot run:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test_myapp.info_myappauthentication' doesn't exist")
```

This happens on post-migrate stage of database initialization:

```
# python manage.py test -v 3 info
...
Running post-migrate handlers for application info
...
Adding permission 'info | myapp authentication | Can add myapp authentication'
Adding permission 'info | myapp authentication | Can change myapp authentication'
Adding permission 'info | myapp authentication | Can delete myapp authentication'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
...
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test_myapp.info_myappauthentication' doesn't exist")
```

My INSTALLED_APPS is as follows:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'tastypie',
    'taggit',
    'info',
```

)

I am unable to figure out which package adds this table, as this is not part of the project and what can be done to fix this?

Comment: have you tried running a migration with `--fake-initial` first?

Comment: @Remi, yes. I did run this.

Comment: Your table seems to be coming from the info package. If it is third-party, check for updates on django 1.9...

Comment: Actually, _info_ is my own package